# Folder specific cucumber-reporting without parallel run?

Tags: karate

Was wondering if I could get setup cucumber-reporting for specific folders?

For example in the https://github.com/intuit/karate#naming-conventions, in *CatsRunner.java* i set up the third party cucumber reporting? without parallel execution. please advise or direct me on how to set it up.

Rationale. its easier to read and helps me in debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always recommended to use the [3rd party Cucumber Reporting](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report) when you want HTML reports. And you can create as many Java classes similar to the [`DemoTestParallel`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java) in different packages. The first argument to [`CucumberRunner.parallel()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution) needs to be a Java class - and by default, the same package *and* sub-folders will be scanned for `*.feature` files.

BUT I think your question is simply how to easily debug a single feature in dev-mode. Easy, just use the `@RunWith(Karate.class)` JUnit runner: [video](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/935029435140489216) | [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-html-report)

Comment: i did the JUnit runner instructions that you provided. but its not coming out as pretty as shown in the video.
an example
https://imgur.com/a/GMW48

also it doesnt show the print statements either.

Comment: @JawadKalia you are on an old version. please use the latest 0.6.2 ! and don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.