# How to limit the report generation only for specific feature file in karate framework?

Tags: karate

I am having 3 feature file and I am trying to execute specific feature in karate using
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:Karate/Karate/APIM_LAYER.feature") over the test runner class.
But on execution, we are able to find reports for all the 3 feature files present in the "target/sure-fire reports path".
Please let us know is there a way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry there isn't enough info in this ticket to understand what you are doing wrong. try harder please.

Comment: My requirement-Need to generate cucumber html report without parallel execution .  please let me know is there way to meet this?

Comment: yes. use the parallel runner and set thread count to 1

Comment: we tried, even we set count to 1, feature file is running two time, one for(test runner clas which run by karate.class) another is for ( genrating cucumber reports).                   @Test

        public void testParallel() {

            String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";

            KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath);

            generateReport(karateOutputPath);

              

        }

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to `V0.6.2`, and when you run with `@RunWith(Karate.class)` with `Cucumber options` it will run those files sequentially and generate pretty html reports for each feature file.

As for the location of the reports, its usually mentioned in the console/terminal.

So make a testfolderunner.java file. add your cucumber options and then from terminal do `mvn test -D test=testfolderunner`

Al the best

Comment: this question could be a duplicate of this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894173/folder-specific-cucumber-reporting-without-parallel-run

therefor i was able to answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you still have the `@RunWith(Karate.class)` annotation even though it is clearly mentioned in the documentation that you should NOT use it for the parallel runner. Please confirm.

Comment: yes. we have two separate class one testrunner with @RunWith(Karate.class)  and another class having @Test containing code for generating cucumber reports without having @RunWith(Karate.class)

Comment: I am requesting this question to be closed because there is no way for anyone on earth to understand or replicate your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To be simple, my requirement is to get cucumber html reports using karate framework as per the documentation i have implemented separate class contain https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution this code .

Comment: @siva huh ? all the best !